# How do I pick multiple items out of a dynamically generated list in javascript & html?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to add multiple products to a table from a dynamically generated list, where each item has a button to add it to the table. It's not working now because when I click a product, it adds it to the table and then if I click another item in the list, it just replaces the first item in the list. This list is dynamically generated because it's coming from a database.

html:

```
<form action="insert.php" method= "POST" name = "productsForm">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><label>Customer Name:</label></th>
                    <th><label>Phone:</label></th>
                    <th><label>Email:</label></th>
                    <th><label>RO | PO:</label></th>
                    <th><label>Address:</label></th>
                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtCustomerName" id = "txtCustomerName"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtPhone" id = "txtPhone"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtEmail" id= "txtEmail"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtRopo" id= "txtRopo"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtAddress" id= "txtAddress"></td>
                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><label>SKU:</label></th>
                    <th><label>Product Name:</label></th>
                    <th><label>Quantity:</label></th>
                    <th><label>Retail Price:</label></th>
                    <th><label>List Price:</label></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtSKU" id = "txtSKU"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtProductName" id= "txtProductName"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtQuantity" id= "txtQuantity"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtRetailPrice" id= "txtRetailPrice"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtListPrice" id= "txtListPrice"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtSKU1" id = "txtSKU1"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtProductName1" id= "txtProductName1"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtQuantity1" id= "txtQuantity1"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtRetailPrice1" id= "txtRetailPrice1"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtListPrice1" id= "txtListPrice1"></td>
                </tr>
                <tfoot>
                    <th><label id = "lblTotal">Total:</label><input type="text" name="txtTotal" id = "txtTotal"><input type="button" value= "Add" id = "addTotals"></button> </th>
                    
                </tfoot>
                    
                
                                   
            
            </table>    
            <button type="submit" name="submitOrder">Submit</button>                
        </form>
```

JavaScript - this function makes the list:

```
function populateProductList(jsonArr){                
    
    var html = "";

    html += `<ol id="myULProducts">`;
            
    for(var x = 0; x < jsonArr.length; x++){
                                
        html += `
        <li SKU = "${jsonArr[x].SKU}">
        <a href="#" class="products">                
            <strong>Product SKU:</strong> ${jsonArr[x].SKU} 
            <br><strong>Product Name:</strong> ${jsonArr[x].product_name} 
            <br><strong>Retail Price:</strong> ${jsonArr[x].retail_price}
            <br><strong>List Price:</strong> ${jsonArr[x].list_price}
                    <br><br></a>
                    <button type="button" class="btnAddProductToOrder">Add to Order</button>    
                </li>
        </div>`
    }
    html += `</ol>`;
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    ul.innerHTML = html;

    var tableContainer = document.getElementById("product-list-container");
    tableContainer.innerHTML = "";
    tableContainer.appendChild(ul);

    tableContainer.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    //populateCardGroupList();
    var target = evt.target;
    //if statement to see if the classList has a button edit
        if(target.classList.contains("btnAddProductToOrder")){
            //get the id of the card group clicked
            var selectedId = target.closest("li").getAttribute("SKU");
            //get the card group attached to that id and pass it the rest of the json Array of objects
            var selectedProduct = getProductId(selectedId, jsonArr);
            populateOrderFormProducts(selectedProduct);                

        }
        
        
    });
    
    
}
```

JavaScript - this function adds the clicked item in the list to the product table below

```
function populateOrderFormProducts(jsonArr){        
    document.getElementById("txtSKU").value = jsonArr.SKU;
    document.getElementById("txtProductName").value = jsonArr.product_name;
    document.getElementById("txtQuantity").value = 1;
    document.getElementById("txtRetailPrice").value = jsonArr.retail_price;
    document.getElementById("txtListPrice").value = parseFloat(jsonArr.list_price);
}
```

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: I honestly can't, I have too many model and dataaccess classes. I'd like to check to see if the first document.getElementById("txtSKU").value is empty, if it is, grab the 2nd clicked li element and put it in <td><input type="text" name="txtSKU1" id = "txtSKU1"></td> But the problem is in the "if" statement in the populateProductList function